# Serializing a tree in php issue

Tags: php

Hi My Objective is to serialize a tree from all my species records to a file.

The Database is one table that is self referencing, basically it contains all the species and the classification levels for them. so for example we have a turtle record below

```
                Taxonomic_units Table
              ------------------------
           Tsn_id   name  parent_id  rank_id

           123     turtle    210       220
           210     turtle_genius  893   210
           893     turtle_family  323   200
           323     turtle_order  242   190
           242     turtle_class  555   180
           555     turtle_phylum  888   170
           888     animal_kingdom  0   0
```

so to build a tree, I'm querying every species record and getting every parent via a recursive method, how should I assemble them in a tree structure? I'm a bit lost and would appreciate some help in getting started. thank you

Comment: Just mark each node you visit (`mark[$node]=TRUE;`) and don't check marked nodes again.

Comment: This code may help you build the tree: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17621885/1744633

Answer (score 0):

You can either build the tree in an array or in an object. Your choice. I'm using array. I assume you have a function `get_row($id)` the returns something like this...

```
array("Tsn_id" => 123,
      "name" => "turtle",
      "parent_id" => 210,
      "rank_id" => 220);
```

I'll assume that you have a function `get_parent($id)` and `get_children($id)` that, respectively, fetches the parent row (as an associative array) and the children (as an array of associative arrays).

You can then do things like this... `build_tree($id)` is probably what you want, but I've included a few other functions that may help.

```
// determine the root row for any node in the tree
function get_root($id) {
  if (!get_parent($id))
    return get_row($id);

  $last = array("Tsn_id" => $id);
  while ($node = get_parent($last["Tsn_id"])) 
    $last = $node;

  return $last;
}

// if you're trying to build the tree from a leaf node, grab the root first... 
function build_tree_from_leaf($id) {
  $root = get_root($id);
  return build_tree($root["Tsn_id"]);
}

// build a tree from the given node
function build_tree($id) {
  $node = get_row($id);
  $node["children"] = array();
  $children = get_children($id);
  foreach ($children as $child) {
    $subtree = build_tree($child["Tsn_id"]);
    $node["children"][] = $subtree;
  }

  return $node;
}
```